# Easeljs - optimalisation

Tags: javascript, easeljs

The **EaselJS.js library** has a lot of functions that I don't need in my project (I don't call them). Is there a way, to detect these functions and remove them for every single project?
I need to reduce the file size as much as possible.

P.S. My easeljs.js is generated in Adobe Flash CC.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to build the source yourself.

1. Check out source from [GitHub](https://github.com/CreateJS/). Each library has its own repository.
2. Edit the `build/config.json`, and remove the classes you don't need.
3. Install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and then the npm dependencies. Check out the [readme in GitHub](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/tree/master/build) for instructions on building.

Note that Flash CC just uses a CDN version of the CreateJS libs (which are also bundled in their respective versions of Flash CC). You *may* need to make sure to use the version of the libraries that Flash CC expects, otherwise it might be using deprecated functionality.

If filesize is an issue, using the remotely hosted libs on the CreateJS CDN is a good approach. With over 8 Billion hits/month, many users may already have the CDN versions in their browser cache.

*[edit for clarification]*
Note that this only removes the classes, and does not operate on the function level.